# iPad/iPhone Dev: displayViewController Is Rendering Portrait in Landscape Orientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation, modalviewcontroller

The following code works but my orientation is landscape and the view comes and goes in portrait.  Any ideas?

```
-(void)displayFirstScreen
{
    UIViewController *displayViewController=[[UIViewController alloc] init];
    displayViewController.view = displaySplash;
    [self presentModalViewController:displayViewController animated:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(removeScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];

    [displayViewController release];
}

-(void)removeScreen
{
    [[self modalViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might address your problem

http://aralbalkan.com/2334